# How do I combine verbs?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions

Is it possible to shorten verbs which consist of more than one part when they are used together? For example, from the first sentence to the second below.

> I had gone and had seen the city.
>
> I had gone and seen the city.

Which of the two is corrrect?

Comment: Wouldn't it be correct to say "I went and saw the city"?

Comment: No, because I was referring to either the action which had started and ended in the past as a form of accomplishment, or the action which had been interrupted by something else. 
E.g. "I had gone and had seen the city, when I fell ill abruptly." where the third verb would be in the past tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both forms are perfectly valid, and the choice is largely a matter of style.

The first version places slightly more emphasis on the "seeing", so it *might* be taken to imply the speaker gave more time and attention to sightseeing.

The second version slightly conflates the "going" and "seeing" into a single semantic unit. This *might* be taken to imply the purpose of going was for sightseeing, an implication which is far weaker in the first version.

Comment: Why is saw not the correct choice here over seen?

Comment: Because *seen* is the past participle, and when you use *had* as an auxiliary verb, you need to use *seen.* Even with the implied had, **I had gone and saw the city* would be wrong. That would be short for *I had gone and I saw the city,* the tenses of which don't make any sense. *I had arrived, and saw the city* does make sense, but I think you need the comma.

Comment: @Chad: Because you'd be mixing tenses. If you want to use "saw" you'd normally say *"I went and saw the city"*.

Comment: @Fumblefingers - I guess I just do not like the phrasing of the the sentence in either way your phrasing would be my preference over either of the 2 above. Or something like "I was not there because I had gone to see the city."

Comment: @Chad: Per my comment to Phil's answer, in both OP's versions we have little reason to suppose seeing the city/sightseeing was necessarily part or all of the motivation for going. But if you use "went/saw" that interpretation is at the very least strongly implied.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It seems implied here as well. perhaps less so in the first sentence. But if you wish to draw the distiction about intent then I think it woul be better to seperate the statements or use a adverb like already.

Comment: @Chad: Agreed - but I'm not trying to imply *or* exclude "intent", since OP hasn't given that context. Don't forget some speakers might even wish to be unforthcoming about the purpose of going. They might want to imply they chose to go on a sightseeing holiday, and not admit it was really just a business trip with a bit of free time.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are valid, however most English speakers would probably instead say:

> I had gone to see the city

*I had gone* lets the listener know that you are speaking in past tense, and now you can use the unconjugated form of *see*.

This is similar to Spanish:

> Voy a ir la biblioteca.

Can be translated to

> I am going (present tense) to go to the library (unconjugated)

Though this is not the case for all sentences, it works well for your example.

Comment: "I had gone to see the city" explicitly says that seeing the city was the purpose of going, but both of OP's originals could be used even if the only reason for going was, say, to deal with some official business.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was looking for clarification on how to combine verbs when both are in the perfect tense, but your explanation is certainly useful too. =)